# SQL Looping temp table and reading data

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I have following script to create temp data

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(100), @Marks INT
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE
(
   [Name][nvarchar](100) NULL,
   [Marks][INT] NULL
)

INSERT INTO @MYTABLE ([Name],[Marks]) VALUES ('Mark',50);
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE ([Name],[Marks]) VALUES ('Steve',50);
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE ([Name],[Marks]) VALUES ('Don',50);
```

Now I want loop it, as shown in below script

```
SELECT @MaxPK = MAX(PK) from @MYTABLE
WHILE @PK <= @MaxPK
BEGIN
 SET @Name =  SELECT Name from @MYTABLE 
 SET @Marks =  SELECT Marks from @MYTABLE   
 print @Name
 print @Marks
 SET @PK = @PK + 1
END
```

But I get error near SELECT statement.

"Incorrect syntax near the keyword SELECT"!

Comment: Maybe it's because that select statement returns multiple rows, not a single value, and you cannot set multiple rows to your @Name variable

Comment: Apart from anything else `PK` doesn't exist in `@MYTABLE`. And why do you need to loop through the rows one by one anyway? And if you really do have such a need why not use a cursor to fetch into `@Name,@Marks,@PK` instead of simulating one with a while loop?

Comment: Hi Dark, i will add WHERE condition so that it always return single row.

Comment: Martin, I do not have much idea on CURSOR so i used WHILE loop and its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two rows where you set the variables can be put together like this. That way you will only scan the table once.

```
SELECT @Name = Name, @Marks = Marks FROM @MYTABLE
```

Just know that the row chosen to be put in your variables is completely arbitary (and will probably be the same row every time) unless you add a whereclause.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below while loop:

```
WHILE @PK <= @MaxPK
BEGIN
 SELECT @Name = Name, @Marks = Marks from @MYTABLE
 print @Name
 print @Marks
END
```

Note: I guess, a where condition is required in select statement in order to print all data.